# Trouble scraping weather data from Google

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a program that will scrape wind speed and direction data from Google. I've seen other results online where it works out fine, but for some reason, it's not working out for me. I am specifically interested in scraping the elements with "img" tags. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import bs4
import geocoder

lat, long = 40.776903698619975, -74.45007646247723

base_url = r"https://www.google.com/search?q="

geoc = geocoder.osm([lat, long], method='reverse').json["raw"]["address"]

search_query = geoc["state"] + " " +  geoc["country"] + " wind conditions"
lowest_admin_levels = ("municipality", "town", "city", "county")
level_found = False
for level in lowest_admin_levels:
    try:
        search_query = geoc[level] + " " + search_query
        level_found = True
        break
    except KeyError:
        continue

url = base_url + search_query.replace(" ", "+")
print(url)
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('img'))
```

The lat/long variables could be any coordinates, those are just examples. `soup.find_all('img')` returns just one "img" element, when in reality, the page has multiple "img"s containing arrows rotated according to the wind direction, which you can see in this link https://www.google.com/search?q=Morris+Township+New+Jersey+United+States+wind+conditions. Thank you!

Comment: The images are being loaded with JavaScript, I disabled JavaScript to verify and the images no longer show, and `requests` can't render JavaScript. Selenium can load JavaScript rendered pages so you could try that.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment already says, Google loads the images **dynamically** using **JavaScript**. The requests library and Beautiful soup are not able to get those **JavaScript loaded images**. That's why **you need Selenium**, to get those images.

## Installation

1. `pip install selenium`
2. `pip install webdriver-manager`

## Solution

```py
import geocoder

# New imports
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

lat, long = 40.776903698619975, -74.45007646247723

BASE_URL = r"https://www.google.com/search?q="

geoc = geocoder.osm([lat, long], method='reverse').json["raw"]["address"]

search_query = geoc["state"] + " " +  geoc["country"] + " wind conditions"
lowest_admin_levels = ("municipality", "town", "city", "county")

for level in lowest_admin_levels:
    try:
        search_query = geoc[level] + " " + search_query
        break
    except KeyError:
        continue

url = BASE_URL + search_query.replace(" ", "+")

chrome_options = Options()
# The options make the browser headless, so you don't see it
# comment out those two lines to see whats happening
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options) # You could specify the path to the chrome driver instead
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

imgs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img') # all the image tags

for img in imgs:
    image_source = img.get_attribute('src') # The src of the img tag
    print(image_source)
```

When you **remove the headless option**, you will see what selenium “sees”. Using Selenium, you can also **click around** on the website and **interact** with it, as you would as a **normal user**.

Answer (score 0):

It's doesn't require `geocoder` nor `selenium`. Check out [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to visually grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element.

Also, you can get **wind direction** from the same element, e.g. `class='wob_t'` -> `area-label`:

```html
<span class="wob_t" style="display:inline;text-align:right" aria-label="8 km/h From northwest Tuesday 10:00">8 km/h</span>
```

Which is the same as in the `<img>` element (*look at* `alt`):

```html
<img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/m/images/weather/wind_unselected.svg" alt="8 km/h From northwest" style="transform-origin:50% 50%;transform:rotate(408deg);width:16px" aria-hidden="true" data-atf="1" data-frt="0" class="">
```

Code and [full example that scrapes more in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Weather-Answer-Box-bs4-python-serpapi#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "london weather",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')


for weather_result in soup.select('.wob_noe .wob_hw'):
  try:
    wind_speed = weather_result.select_one('.wob_t').text

    '''
    extracts elements, splits the string by a SPACE, and grabs 2nd and 4th index,
    and then joins via SPACE. Or just use regex instead.

    Example:
    7 mph From northwest Sunday 9:00 AM ---> From northeast
    '''
    wind_direction = ' '.join(weather_result.select_one('.wob_t')['aria-label'].split(' ')[2:4])

    print(f"{wind_speed}\n{wind_direction}\n")

  except:
    pass # or None instead

----------
'''
8 mph
From northeast

11 mph
From east

9 mph
From northeast
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Essentially, you don't need to figure out extracting part of the process and all that really needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON and use whatever you need from it (*apart from bypass blocks from Google or maintain the parser over time*).

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "london weather",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

forecast = results['answer_box']['forecast']
print(json.dumps(forecast, indent=2))

----------
'''
[
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "weather": "Partly cloudy",
    "temperature": {
      "high": "72",
      "low": "57"
    },
    "thumbnail": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/weather/48/partly_cloudy.png"
  }
...
]
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.